# make webpage work offline

Tags: html, iis, offline-caching

I have made a simple web application with a style sheet a javascript file and a HTML page, I have configured this on local IIS, I want this web page to work also when I stop the IIS, The code of the HTML page is as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="clock.appcache">
<head>
    <title>Clock</title>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>The time is: <output id="clock"></output></p>
</body>
</html>
```

the clock appcache file contains the name of the styleshteet and the javascript file which I want to cache at the local end.the application does catch the files at my local end but does not work when I stop the IIS
Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong in here.

Regards